# Why isn't Tristram bound by blood law?

Tags: stardust

In *Stardust*, Septimus is bound by "blood-law" to revenge Primus. 
Why isn't Tristram bound by this as well, since blood-law seems to apply to the Stormhold lineage.

Comment: Because he has no idea what the bloody law is, because he has no idea he's in that lineage, because he has no idea who Primus is or how he died... etc?

Comment: They made it sound like it was some magic contract, like everything else.

Answer (score 4):

The concept of blood-law in Stormhold appears to be one of custom rather than forming a *magical* contract. You may wish to note that revenging his brother isn't actually high on Septimus' list of priorities, largely because he doesn't actually care for his brother. It's more a question of it being '[the done thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chivalry)'.

> ...now I must revenge your sad carcass, and **all for the honor of our
> blood** and the Stormhold.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Stardust - A Novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardust_(novel))</sup></sub>

The principle of 'blood law' is that the soul of the deceased cannot rest until revenged. In our reality this is based on religious conviction whereas in Stormhold, ghosts are an **actual factual certainty**. Interestingly, this concept is American-Indian rather than Western.

> In contrast to the Western notion of justice, blood law was based on
> harmony and balance. **It was believed that the soul/ghost of the victim
> would be forced to wander the earth, not allowed to go to the
> afterlife, unless harmony was restored. The death of the killer (or
> member of the killer's clan) restored the balance.**
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia - Blood Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_Law)</sup>

At this point Tristran is neither aware of his relationship to the deceased, nor his obligations. It's worth pointing out that he does actually fulfill the vendetta with the death of his uncle's killer.